# Error: Version Error while adding facebook dependency

Tags: android, facebook, dependencies, build.gradle

I am implementing facebook integration in my project but I am stuck as I add facebook sdk dependency in my project it gives me an error.

When i am going to add facebook sdk dependencies in build.gradle, it gives me error of mixing version.

[image]

Comment: add your gradle app file with question

Comment: This error is causing because there is mismatch b/w library versions in gradle,put all libraries same version support.

Comment: did you add your gradle file this facebook sdk      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'   ???

Comment: @YBDevi is right! you should use same versions of all libraries otherwise it gies this kind of error, check your all libraries versions and correct it.

Comment: you can also try this - compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' and change  compileSdkVersion 25, targetSdkVersion 25.

Answer (score 2):

The [Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/build.gradle) is using support libraries version **25.3.1**, so you have to exclude them to use the most recent support libraries:

Something like:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```

Otherwise you have to use the support libraries v.25.3.1 instead of 26.+.

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
...
```

Comment: I tried this, but ended up with No resource identifier found errors...is there anything else I need to add to tell Gradle to use the 26.1.0 libraries?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Just want to add that `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0` doesn't work with `4.30.0` and `4.31.0` and it gives mixing version errors

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the specific Version of the implementation, go to this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/ 
and add latest version. If the error still persists you may have to lower the version number. At the time of answering this, 4.31.0 is the latest version, but 4.29.0 worked for me.